# how to include file from child directory in php

Tags: php, syntax, path

My file lies in /var/www/spywgc/adm/index.php folder .... and the file i want to include lies in var/www/spywgc/adm/rpt/lib_pivot.php

I want to include lib_pivot.php in index.php..... The lib_pivot.php interns include a file var/www/spywgc/lib_gen file.....

I wrote a syntax of  in index.php file... but, it keeps giving me error....

Someone please explain me what to do.

Comment: OP says: "Fatal error: main() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../../lib_gen.php' (include_path='.:/usr/PEAR:/home/facetime/PEAR:/usr/bin/pear_old') in /var/www/html/spywgc/adm/rpt/lib_pivot.php on line 1........This is the error I got" (from comment on answer).

Comment: Can you include your code please?!

Answer (score 1):

`include('rpt/lib_pivot.php');` will work, unless there's something I'm misunderstanding.

When you call `include()`, and don't begin with a '/', it starts in the directory of the caller script.  So if `index.php` is in `adm/`, then just progress from inside `adm/` further down the path.

#### Section 2

If I understand this correctly (it's kind of confusing):

> The lib_pivot.php interns include a file var/www/spywgc/lib_gen file

then inside of `lib_pivot.php` use `include('../../lib_gen.php');` to come up two directories from the `rpt/` directory.

Comment: You could always use the absolute paths rather than relative.  `include('/var/www/spywgc/adm/rpt/lib_pivot.php');` and `require('/var/www/spywgc/lib_gen.php');`

Comment: Apparently @Phoenix that's not the issue. @Jason's answer (with abs paths) above threw the same error.

Comment: Apparently then, lib_gen.php either does not exist at that location, or the Apache user (or whatever server you're using) doesn't have access to the file.  Make sure it exists, if so, chmod it to 777 (for testing purposes only, do not leave it as 777), if it functions then, it's a file permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's hard to solve without you telling us the actual error, but this should work

`include('/var/www/spywgc/adm/rpt/lib_pivot.php');`

If anything you might have been missing the "/" at the start of the string

Comment: Fatal error: main() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../../lib_gen.php' (include_path='.:/usr/PEAR:/home/facetime/PEAR:/usr/bin/pear_old') in /var/www/html/spywgc/adm/rpt/lib_pivot.php on line 1....this is the error I got..

Answer (score 0):

You have no showed the `include()` statement that resides on line 1 inside of `lib_pivot.php`...thats where you error is comming from